# java web UI testing tool, something that converts DOM to objects?

Tags: java, testing

is there a java UI testing tool (web) that converts the DOM into a java object of sort?

So I can do something like:

```
browser.GoToPage("google").FindButton("search").click();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html) allows you to do this.

Comment: btw, does this work without having a browser actually running on the computer?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) - it has a very useful tool + an API.